# Changing each cell in CSV

Tags: python, csv

In my CSV file I have the following:

```
     Name    Installs 
----|-------------------
    |a         4+
    |b         15+
    |c         60+
    |d         5+
```

How could I iterate through the Installs column using pandas to remove the plus at the end? And save the contents to an existing CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df["Installs"].str.strip("+")` or `str.rstrip("+")`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], "Installs": ["4+", "15+", "60+", "5+"]})
df["Installs"] = df["Installs"].str.strip("+")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Installs Name
0        4    a
1       15    b
2       60    c
3        5    d
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_file_name_here.csv")
df["Installs"] = df["Installs"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("x","")
df.to_csv("your_new_file_path_here.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use or slice it out with `Series.str[:-1]`:

```
df['Installs']=df['Installs'].str[:-1]
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
  Installs Name
0        4    a
1       15    b
2       60    c
3        5    d
```

If want them as integers, do:

```
df['Installs']=df['Installs'].str[:-1].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('csv_name.csv')
df['Installs']=df['Installs'].str.strip('+')
df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this manually with `str.rstrip()`:

```
with open('data.csv') as f, open('output.csv', mode='w') as o:
    for line in map(str.rstrip, f):
        o.write(line.rstrip('+') +'\n')
```

Which gives the following *output.csv*:

```
     Name    Installs
----|-------------------
    |a         4
    |b         15
    |c         60
    |d         5
```

You can also use `str.rsplit()` here:

```
o.write(line.rsplit('+', 1)[0] + '\n')
```